# Header Search Paths error

Tags: ios, frameworks

I am adding a private framework Message under the Framework section. What will be the Header search paths for that? I have used **"$(SDKROOT)$(SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DIR)/Message"**, but this gives the following error:

```
warning: directory not found for option '-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Message'
```

Comment: don't use private frameworks :)

Comment: I know the problem but as per my client required IMEI number. That way I am trying to fetch IMEI number using private frame work. Also I am trying to use Erica Sadun’s code but getting valid result. I am using Xcode 4.6